# Can the compiler infer object Type when omitted in method call?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the following situation:

```
public class Storage
{
 public T GetSingleByID<T>(long id) where T : IStorable
 {
  // do some magic to return the object based on T and the id
 }
}

public class Beer : IStorable
{
}

public class BeerStorage : Storage
{
}


BeerStorage beerStorage = new BeerStorage();
Beer beer = beerStorage.GetSingleByID(5); /* compile error here */
```

For obvious reasons I get a compile error because the Type cannot be inferred. Fair enough. But is there a way to make the compiler able to infer the correct type based on the fact that I'm calling `GetSingleByID` on a `BeerStorage` rather than a `Storage`? I'd say there should be a way for the compiler to see this difference and infer T for me?

How to make a relation between `Beer` and `BeerStorage` in such a way that the compiler can infer the correct type?

Comment: There's no relationship between `Beer` and `BeerStorage` that I can see. Declaring your `beer` variable as a `Beer` doesn't really help here...

Comment: @BoltClock, yes I know there isnt a relation between `Beer` and `BeerStorage` and that results in the compile error. My question is, how to make such relation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @delnal, no, obviously that won't work. But based on something else that I don't know off perhaps. Can you give me directions on how you would solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: You should derive `BeerStorage` from `Storage<Beer>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to declare the generic type parameter and constraint on your `Storage` class, rather than its `GetSingleByID()` method:

```
public class Storage<T> where T : IStorable
{
 public T GetSingleByID(long id)
 {
  // do some magic to return the object based on T and the id
 }
}
```

Then extend it to `BeerStorage` with `Beer` as the generic type like so:

```
public class BeerStorage : Storage<Beer>
{
}
```

Your calling code should then work. You can even switch the `Beer` declaration for the `var` keyword and the compiler will know that `BeerStorage.GetSingleByID()` returns a `Beer` instance:

```
BeerStorage beerStorage = new BeerStorage();
var beer = beerStorage.GetSingleByID(5); /* beer is a Beer instance */
```

Comment: Simple gap in my (limited) knowledge on generics. I didnt know you could specify the generic type parameter on the class. Perfect solution! Will accept answer after time period has expired.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Thanks for the edit — my copypasta process obviously needs some looking at ;)

Comment: I made the same mistake at first. So when I edited my answer to fix it, I notices you made the same copypaste mistake as I did.

Answer (score 4):

C# does not infer generic parameters from the return value. So your code doesn't work. If you want to keep your current code, you'd need to specify `T` at every call site `Beer beer = beerStorage.GetSingleByID<Beer>(5);`.

I'd make `Storage` generic, and then specialize by substituting `Beer` for `T` when defining the `BeerStorage` class:

```
public class Storage<T>
  where T : IStorable
{
 public T GetSingleByID(long id) 
 {
  // do some magic to return the object based on T and the id
 }
}

public class Beer : IStorable
{
}

public class BeerStorage : Storage<Beer>
{
}
```

Comment: +1 Indeed that is the correct approach, as suggested by BoltClock as well. Thank you for your answer.